# Get usernames and IP addresses via tcpdump (or another capture tool) connecting to a MySQL server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, users

I've MySQL installed on my Ubuntu server.
Because I would like to clean up my users they're currently active in MySQL, I would like to check first which users - and from which host - are connecting to the MySQL server.

The only thing I need is: which host is connecting and which username is used.

I tried to perform this task with tcpdump, but with no luck so far. It looks easy to get the whole query, but I do not get the above mentioned information.
The server is heavily used, if there is no other option I can enable the general query log, but if it is possible I would like to prevent this option.

Does anyone have a tip for me on how I can perform this task?

Answer (score 1):

1. list currently active sessions

In your mysql prompt, you may typ the following for displaying currently active sessions:

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

Or this mysql query (which return the same info):

```
mysql> select * from information_schema.processlist;
```

And you may only get the {user,host} pair like that:

```
mysql> select User,Host from information_schema.processlist;
```

2. log and display query history.

Turn on mysql query log

```
set global log_output = 'table';
set global general_log = 'on';
```

See all the executed queries

```
select * from mysql.general_log;
```

See the timestamp, the host_user and the related query:

```
select event_time,user_host,argument from mysql.general_log;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: With "show processlist" I can only see the currrent logged in sessions. However, users they do a small query will not pop up in this list. I've to monitor the server a couple of days and after that time I would like to have a list with hosts and users. For that reason I thought tcpdump is a good solution, but I don't get the host/user extracted from a tcpdump file.

Comment: I updated my answer including a part 2. I think it match your need better.